# There's a blue vertical line in the notice banner

Tags: bug, post-notice

Blue vertical line has just appeared in the bounty notice banner. Is this by-design or a bug?

[image]

Comment: That looks like a quote.

Comment: *Finally* maybe we will get a proper blockquote style that doesn’t look like a code block!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that is by design, since today.

From [Yaakov's Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344273/158100) on MSE:

> The display of bounty notices with custom text has been updated to preserve double line breaks and to highlight custom text in a more visible and consistent way.

The blue line probably goes under the *more visible and consistent way* label ...